SQL query to read file name and content from physical location
I need SQL query or function/procedure, that can read all file names and content from physical location and insert into the SQL table. There are two things here-

All the files are text file (.txt)

And file name should not be duplicate (need to add condition in query)


My table looks like below:

First column (Id) is the primary key and identity column. Second column (File_Name) is to store file name (without extension) and third column (File_Content) is to store file content or data.
My file directory or physical location looks like below:

And the result or SQL table data should looks like below:


As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

And its not really something you should be doing in your database. A database is for storing data, not reading from your file system. Write yourself a PowerShell script or similar.

You need to exec xp_cmdshell in your queries. not possible using pure sql queries

@AliSheikhpour,can you share any example?

Using pure SQL queries you cannot access files and file manipulation. You may need to use Python or Shell command along with your SQL queries:
This is how you can read file list in a temp table and then copying into a real SQL table:
--Enabling xp_cmdshell 
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
reconfigure;
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
reconfigure;
   
-- Creating a temp table and list files
DECLARE @DirCommand NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @DirOutput table (FileName NVARCHAR(50), FileContent NVARCHAR(MAX));
set @DirCommand = 'DIR /B "C:\repository\*.txt"';
insert into #TempFiles (FileName, FileContent)
exec xp_cmdshell @DirCommand;

-- Copying data from temp table into a sql table
insert into YOURTABLE (file_name, file_content)
select FileName, FileContent from @DirOutput;

-- Disable xp_cmdshell to enhance security
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;
reconfigure;


xp_cmdshell is used to execute shell commands, including invoking PowerShell commands indirectly. Am I right? @DaleK

by shell I only mean a command-line interpreter. I am not sure if xp_cmdshell is using PowerShell or is something like shell in sql server @DaleK

Ar, it was a spelling mistake then
